# Sharing Helper Funactions across Views in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a Helper method that I need to use across multiple views. I tried to using the following information: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx. I have defined this Helper method in /App_Code/Helpers.cshtml. My views are located at

```
/resources/_Layout.cshtml
/Views/Index.cshtml
/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
```

If I reference my Helper function in _Layout.cshtml everything works fine. However, if I reference my Helper function in the other views, I get a runtime error. The runtime error says:

CS0103: The name 'MyFunction' does not exist in the current context

My Helper method looks like the following:

```
/App_Code/Helpers.cshtml
------------------------
@helper MakeUrlRelative(string url)
{
    @MyNamespace.MyClass.MakeUrlRelative(HttpContext.Current.Request, url)
}
```

When I reference it in /Views/Index.cshtml, I use it like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@MakeUrlRelative("/resources/css/app.css")" />
```

When I reference it in /Views/Home/Index.cshtml

```
<a href="@MakeUrlRelative("/home/page2")">click me</a>
```

As  you can see, I'm referencing the MakeUrlRelative method the same way. Its like the Helpers.cshtml file isn't accessible from /Views/Home/Index.cshtml. What would cause this?

Comment: Can you post your helper definition, and a sample view where you try to call it but fails?

Comment: It strange... based on your code non of the calls should work. You are missing the class name `Helpers` in both cases: e.g it should be `@Helpers.MakeUrlRelative("/home/page2")` (razor generates a static class from each file in app_code with the name of the file)